# Error 406 during server deployment on Spring

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc, spring-rest, http-status-code-406

I'm trying to start my simple REST server, but finally I have error 406.
I'm tryed to change my settings in web.xml and dispatcher servlet but It'n didn't help me.

Controller

```
@Controller

public class RestController {
@RequestMapping("/")
public ModelAndView checkUser() {
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
    modelAndView.setViewName("main");
    return modelAndView;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/get-simpleuser", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
@ResponseBody
public User getUser(){
    User user = new User();
    return user;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/get-user/{name}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
@ResponseBody
public User getUser(@PathVariable("name") String name){
    User user = new User();
    user.setName(name);
    return user;
}
```

}

User object

```
@JsonAutoDetect
public class User {
String name;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

}

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"

     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
     version="3.1">

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

dispatcher-servlet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**"
               location="/resources/"/>

<mvc:annotation-driven/>

<context:component-scan base-package="controllers"/>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"

     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>groupId</groupId>
<artifactId>MyRest</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.9.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.9.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.9.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.9.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>au.com.dius</groupId>
        <artifactId>pact-jvm-provider_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.12</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- для валидации введенных данных -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- маппер JSON и Java объектов (новая версия библиотеки) -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Servlet -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

I've downloaded page on adress("/") which not REST, but on other adresses I have error.

Can you tell me where I was wrong.

Thank you!

Comment: I would do a test, remove the attribute "produces=json" from your request, and also JsonAutoDetect from user. I did something similar and just with ResponseBody jackson know need to traduce the object to json, so no need to add extra attributes. Try if works and let me know

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't help. I got: Error 500 "Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No converter found for return value of type: class user.User"

Comment: Why are you using same config for root and dispatcher application context?